# Fritz WLAN USB Stick 1.1 Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: wireless, usb, 17.10

Is anyone familiar with installing the Fritz WLAN USB Stick 1.1 on Ubuntu 17.10?

I tried the following:

Installing the drivers with ndiswrapper gui[image: ndiswrapper gui]

```
gksu ndisgtk
```

Driver is taken from http://www.elektronenblitz63.de/html/fritzstick.html . This has been working on Ubuntu 16 by the way.

No wifi-device is recognized in gnome, though.

[image: Device is not working properly]

Further information, my

```
lsusb
```

output (selected the relevant part):

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 057c:6201 AVM GmbH AVM Fritz!WLAN v1.1 [Texas Instruments TNETW1450]
```

Anyone got hints/ solutions?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day everybody.

Edit:
Result of

```
    dmesg | grep ndis

 [  876.202555] ndiswrapper: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
 [  876.202813] ndiswrapper: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
 [  876.202823] ndiswrapper: module license taints kernel.
 [  876.203807] ndiswrapper version 1.60 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
 [  876.228956] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
 [  902.744926] usbcore: deregistering interface driver ndiswrapper
 [  902.765425] ndiswrapper version 1.60 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
 [  902.772806] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
 [  969.642259] usbcore: deregistering interface driver ndiswrapper
 [  969.670316] ndiswrapper version 1.60 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
 [  969.681944] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
 [ 1073.041785] usbcore: deregistering interface driver ndiswrapper
 [ 1073.072563] ndiswrapper version 1.60 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
 [ 1073.080432] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
 [12809.532371] usbcore: deregistering interface driver ndiswrapper
 [12809.551691] ndiswrapper version 1.60 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
 [12809.558624] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
```

Comment: Did you find and use Windows *XP* drivers? Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep ndis`

Comment: Yeah, I used the XP drivers :o. You think I should look for newer ones?

Edited the question, too.

Comment: Nope. ndiswrapper requires XP drivers and none other. Your dmesg actually doesn't look too bad. Please turn off secure boot in the BIOS or UEFI. With the device inserted please add to your question: `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper` and also: `ndiswrapper -l` That's lower-case L for list .

Comment: Googling for "TNETW1450 linux" (from your lsusb) turns up https://wiki.debian.org/acx which seems to be a relatively current native Linux driver for these - maybe check that out too ?

Comment: @JonasCz Installing the TNETW1450

# wget -P /lib/firmware http://acx100.erley.org/fw/acx111_2.4.0.70-USB/tiacx111usbc1B firmware did the trick for me. Thank you. Just posted this via my WiFi

Comment: @JonasCz Great catch and very helpful. Thank you. I suggest that you convert this to an answer so it can be accepted and upvoted. The searchers will appreciate it.

Comment: @JonasCz U wanna write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that these devices are supported natively on Linux with the `acx-mac80211` driver. Here's a list of the devices this driver supports, from  https://wiki.debian.org/acx, yours is one of them.

```
PCI: 104C:8400 Texas Instruments ACX 100 22Mbps Wireless Interface
PCI: 104C:8401 Texas Instruments ACX 100 22Mbps Wireless Interface
PCI: 104C:9066 Texas Instruments ACX 111 54Mbps Wireless Interface
USB: 0451:60C5 Texas Instruments, Inc. (Device name unknown)
USB: 057C:5601 AVM GmbH AVM Fritz!WLAN [Texas Instruments TNETW1450]
USB: 057C:6201 AVM GmbH AVM Fritz!WLAN v1.1 [Texas Instruments TNETW1450]
USB: 07B8:B21A AboCom Systems Inc WUG2400 802.11g Wireless Adapter [Texas Instruments TNETW1450]
USB: 0CDE:0017 Z-Com (Device name unknown)
USB: 2001:3B00 D-Link Corp. AirPlus DWL-120+ Wireless Adapter [Texas Instruments ACX100USB]
USB: 2001:3B01 D-Link Corp. WLAN Boot Device
```

---

Install the driver by:

1. Installing the firmware for it. For the "AVM Fritz!WLAN v1.1", you can do that by running

   ```
   sudo wget -P /lib/firmware http://acx100.erley.org/fw/acx111_2.4.0.70-USB/tiacx111usbc1B
   ```

   Other devices supported by this driver require other firmware, look in the link above for specifics. This may be all you need to do, as it seems that newer version of Ubuntu already come with the driver. If It doesn't work after installing the firmware and rebooting, you'll need the driver.
2. If WiFi still **does not work**, install the actual driver itself. Text copied from the [Debian wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/acx) for reference:

> 1. Checkout the `http://acx100.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=acx100/acx-mac80211|acx-mac80211`
>      repository:
>
>    git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/acx100/acx-mac80211 acx100-acx-mac80211
> 2. Move the repository directory to `/usr/src` and rename:
>
>    su
>      mv acx100-acx-mac80211 /usr/src/acx-mac80211-git
> 3. Add `acx-mac80211-git` to the tree for building and installing:
>
>    dkms add -m acx-mac80211 -v git
> 4. Build and install the acx-mac80211 module:
>
>    dkms build -m acx-mac80211 -v git
>      dkms install -m acx-mac80211 -v git
> 5. Load the module:
>
>    modprobe acx-mac80211
> 6. If necessary, connect the device to your system.

If this works correctly, you should not need to use ndiswrapper at all.